# jQuery autocomplete, pass data-property of field autocomplete is located in

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have a page with multiple autocomplete-fields. I'd need to pass some additional data of each field that autocomplete is attached to (e.g. "data-field-id="X")

Autocomplete is initialized with class "autocomplete". These autocomplete fields are generated dynamically.

Currently my code looks like this:

```
var autocompleteFields = $(".dynamic-fields.autocomplete");

// autocomplete data getter for necessary fields
if (autocompleteFields.length > 0) {
    autocompleteFields.autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            request.module = 'shared';
            request.page = 'get_autofill_data.php';
            $.ajax({
                url: "ajax.php",
                data: request,
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                success: function (data) {
                    response(data);
                }
            });
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $(this).val(ui.item.value);
        }
    });
}
```

I would need to pass e.g. "data-field-id" -property in request.x of currently used field. Is this possible some how? I couldn't find a clear way to do this in the documentation..

Comment: Are you getting DOM object(s) in autocompleteFields correctly ?

Comment: If getting correct value then 
var dataFieldId = autocompleteFields.attr('data-field-id');
request.x = dataFieldId;
Hope this will work.

Comment: This seems to work when there is one autocomplete-instance, but with two, both get the same data-field-id although it is different in the html.

Comment: If it is more than one, then autocompleteFields is an array. Then you need to iterate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It will work.

```
var autocompleteFields = $(".dynamic-fields.autocomplete");
if (autocompleteFields.length > 0) {
autocompleteFields.autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        request.module = 'shared';
        request.page = 'get_autofill_data.php';
        request.x = $(this)[0].element.attr('data-field-id')
        $.ajax({
            url: "ajax.php",
            data: request,
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                response(data);
            }
        });
    },
    select: function (event, ui) {
        $(this).val(ui.item.value);
    }
});
}
```

Comment: This seems to work just right! Thank you very much :) I tried accessing $(this) earlier, but did not have the key [0] in it.